# How to prove $n=4k+3$ cannot be the sum of two squares, x and y are integers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

To prove that means $n\neq x^2+y^2$,
so I started with $n\equiv 3 (mod 4)$, 
then I don't know how to go on.

Comment: Start with $n = x^2 + y^2$, and look at $x,y$ modulo 4.

Comment: Please search before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be different:

If
$n = x^2+y^2
$
and $n$ is odd,
then one of
$x$ and $y$ is even
and the other is odd
(otherwise their sum is even).

Suppose
$x = 2a$
and
$y = 2b+1$.
Then
$x^2+y^2
=(2a)^2+(2b+1)^2
=4a^2+4b^2+4b+1
=4(a^2+b^2+b)+1
$.

This sum is of the form
$4m+1$,
so it can not be
of the form
$4m+3$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ (or y) $= 4t$ ( 0 mod 4 ), then $x^2 = 16t^2$ ( 0 mod 4 )

If $x$ (or y) $= 4t+1$ ( 1 mod 4 ), then $x^2 = 16t^2 + 8t + 1$ ( 1 mod 4 )

If $x$ (or y) $= 4t+2$ ( 2 mod 4 ), then $x^2 = 16t^2 + 16t + 4$ ( 0 mod 4 )

If $x$ (or y) $= 4t+3$ ( 3 mod 4 ), then $x^2 = 16t^2 + 24t + 9$ ( 1 mod 4 )

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Notice that a square is either congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is any integer than $k^2(mod 4)=0$ or $1$

Now suppose $n=x^2+y^2$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{z}$ than $3=n (mod 4)=(x^2+y^2)mod 4=x^2(mod 4)+y^2(mod4)$,which is contradiction,because no combination of 0 and 1 add up to 3.